# PHPUnit Database Extension - How to have an empty dataset?

Tags: phpunit, dbunit

I want to create a test table that is empty.  Using the Example from digitalsandwich, I want something like:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/TestCase.php';
class BankAccountDBTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
        BankAccount::createTable($this->pdo);
    }

    protected function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($this->pdo, 'sqlite');
    }

    protected function getDataSet()
    {
        return $this->createFlatXMLDataSet(dirname(__FILE__).'/_files/empty-seed.xml');
    }

    public function testEmptyTableBehavior() 
    {
        // test stuff
    }
}
```

Should I be using a different method than createFlatXMLDataSet()?  Or???

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out:

```
...
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/Database/DataSet/DefaultDataSet.php';
class BankAccountDBTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{
...
    protected function getDataSet()
    {
        return new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_DefaultDataSet();
    }
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that this is not true anymore for newer versions. I think since PHPUnit 6.0 they are using namespaces here: `return new PHPUnit\DbUnit\DataSet\DefaultDataSet();`